# Wordpress site migrated but now fonts are not loading correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I've migrated https://resolvered.com and as you can see its not loading the font compared to https://digitalcloud.co.za/resolvered

Would appreciate your advice.
TIA

Answer (score 1):

Sorted. So in future if you delete your fonts folder in wp-content it will reset the link and fonts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The paths to your fonts are incorrects, the network show a "404 not found" when trying to load the fonts. Your project is trying to get the font where at a place they are not.

The URL on Digitalcloud:
https://digitalcloud.co.za/resolvered/wp-content/fonts/manrope/xn7_YHE41ni1AdIRqAuZuw1Bx9mbZk79FN_C-b_Tfc7AKrU.woff

The URL on resolvered.com:
https://resolvered.com/home/digita39/public_html/resolvered/wp-content/fonts/manrope/xn7_YHE41ni1AdIRqAuZuw1Bx9mbZk79FN_C-b_Tfc7AKrU.woff

You need to make them available at that path or fix the path where your fonts are required.

Comment: Thx, i see that now but dont know where to edit that hardcode?

Comment: I can't help you for that, as I can't access your WordPress and see how it has been build. If you use plugins for your fonts, search there. If you can't find it, make a search for your font name in your code, you should find it easily with a name like that. If prefer to move your fonts instead, just connect to your WordPress by FTP and place the fonts at the correct place, it will solve the problem.